# How do I get the most recent entry on a timestamp in one table based on a user ID

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to figure out how to merge these two queries.  The 'donors' table is a list of users.  The 'emailLog' table is a list of everytime we send an email to any user.

I would like to write one query that gets all the info about the donor PLUS the last time we sent an email to each donor.

```
SELECT * FROM donor WHERE email != '' AND isConfirmed = '0' 
SELECT timestamp FROM emailLog WHERE email = '$donorEmail' ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 1
```

This is the best I have come up with so far, but it gives a result for every time I send an email, not just the most current.

```
SELECT a.*, b.timestamp AS lastEmail
   FROM donor a 
   LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT timestamp, email 
     FROM emailLog 
     ORDER BY timestamp ASC) b ON a.email = b.email
    WHERE a.email != ''
    AND a.isConfirmed = '0'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple aggregation or correlated subquery?

```
select d.*,
       (select max(el.timestamp)
        from emailLog el
        where el.email = d.email
       ) as lasttimestamp
from donor d
where d.email <> '' and d.isConfirmed = '0'
```

Comment: Seems just the ticket! And since you have avoided the `JOIN` you don't even need the alias names `d`and `el`for the tables anymore...
No - I was wrong - there is the column `email` that appears in both tables. Therefore better keep the alias names!

Comment: Use of table aliases and qualified column names is good practice for SQL queries.

Comment: Yeah, I am sometimes a bit too quick with my comments ... ;-)

Comment: Thank you, Gordon.  First time I have built a query like that.  Wasn't even sure what to search for.